# Custom directive - two way binding not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to write a simple custom directive in Angular that turns a  tag into a toggle button (similar to a checkbox). The code I have written so far updates the internal variable (isolated scope) but the two way binding doesn't seem to work. When I click the button, the button toggles (the css class is appearing and disappearing) but `myVariable` is not updating.

Any help much appreciated!

Usage

```
<button toggle-button="myVariable">My Button</button>
```

Directive code

```
( function() {

var directive = function () {

    return {

        restrict: 'A',

        scope: {
            toggleButton: '=checked'
        },

        link: function( $scope, element, attrs ) {

            $scope.$watch('checked', function(newVal, oldVal) {
                newVal ? element.addClass ('on') : element.removeClass('on');
            });

            element.bind('click', function() {
                $scope.checked = !$scope.checked;
                $scope.$apply();
            });
        }
    };
};


angular.module('myApp')
    .directive('toggleButton', directive );

}());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just replace

```
scope: {
            toggleButton: '=checked'
        }
```

to

```
 scope: {
            checked: '=toggleButton'
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your directive scope is looking for an attribute that doesn't exist.

Try changing:

```
 scope: {
     toggleButton: '=checked'
  },
```

To

```
scope: {
    toggleButton: '='
},
```

The difference is that `=checked` would look for the attribute `checked` whereas `=` will use the same attribute as the property name in the scope object

Will also need to change the `$watch` but you could get rid of it and use `ng-class`

Answer (score 0):

As charlietfl said, you don't need that checked variable. You are making changes to it instead of the external variable.

Here is a fixed version:

```
angular.module('components', [])
    .directive('toggleButton', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope:{
                toggleButton:'='
            },
            link: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {    
                $scope.$watch('toggleButton', function(newVal) {
                    newVal ? $element.addClass ('on') : $element.removeClass('on');
                });
                $element.bind('click', function() {
                    $scope.toggleButton = !$scope.toggleButton;
                    $scope.$apply();
                });
            }

        }
    })

angular.module('HelloApp', ['components'])
```

http://jsfiddle.net/b3b3qkug/1/

Comment: This was a stylistic thing though, surely? I wanted to name it because it made sense internally. Is there a *functional* reason why I shouldn't (as per the answer I have accepted?)